# Playstation DLC Regions, Sharing DLC

Tags: ps4, psn

So, I'm trying to buy a DLC for Naruto To Boruto, Shinobi striker. I have an American Disc of the game and play it in the USA but I have a German account I am playing it on. I asked a Bandai Namco support guy about it and here's what he said :

[image: here's what he said].

But when I called playstation support they said that this is not true, So, my question is, if I make an American PSN account, set it as my primary, and then buy the DLC's for the game, will my German account with all of my saved data be able to download/use the DLC's as well?

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

What the Bandai Namco Support representative said is exactly what you need to do, if you wish to play the DLC on a US game, using a German account.

The Playstation Support representative probably misunderstood your question.

---

> will my German account with all of my saved data be able to download/use the DLC's as well?

Use, yes. Download, no. This may be what the Playstation Support rep misunderstood.

1. Since the game's and DLC's regions must match, you **must** buy a US DLC for your US game. The game won't recognize the DLC otherwise.
2. An account can only buy (and download) games/DLCs from its own region. Therefore you need a US PSN Account to buy and download a US DLC. There is no getting around that. Even if you buy a download code in retail (e.g. GameStop), you still need a US account to redeem the code and download the game/DLC.
3. Since the PS4 is region-free, it can play games/DLCs from any regions. This applies to accounts as well. You can play games/DLCs from any region, using accounts from any regions.
4. Because of points 1 and 2, your German account must access the DLC from your US account. To do that, your US account must be on the same PS4, and the PS4 must be registered as the "Primary PS4" for the US account.

Things to note:

You can't remove the US account from your PS4. If you do, your German account will **no longer** be able to access the DLC, even if the DLC is still on the PS4.

The same is true if you unregister your PS4 as Primary PS4 of your US account (e.g. you sell your US account to someone, and that someone wants to register his own PS4 instead).